# Use ComboBoxEditSettings in Devexpress GridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a OneToMeny relation object model for User and UserGroup like this:

```
public class UserGroup : BaseModel, IEquatable<UserGroup>
{
    private long _userGroupId;
    private string _userGroupName;

    public long UserGroupId
    {
        get { return _userGroupId; }
        set
        {
            _userGroupId = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UserGroupId);
        }
    }

    public string UserGroupName
    {
        get { return _userGroupName; }
        set
        {
            _userGroupName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UserGroupName);
        }
    }

    public UserGroup GetCopy(bool getNew)
    {
        var copy = new UserGroup
        {
            UserGroupId = UserGroupId,
            UserGroupName = UserGroupName,
            State = getNew ? ModelStates.New : State,
        };

        return copy;
    }

    public bool Equals(UserGroup other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return _userGroupId == other._userGroupId;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((UserGroup) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _userGroupId.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class User : BaseModel
{
    private long _userId;
    private string _userName;
    private string _password;
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private List<UserGroup> _userGroups;

    public User()
    {
        _userGroups = new List<UserGroup>();
    }

    public long UserId
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set
        {
            _userId = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UserId);
        }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set
        {
            _userName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UserName);
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Password);
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LastName);
        }
    }

    public List<UserGroup> UserGroups
    {
        get { return _userGroups; }
        set
        {
            _userGroups = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UserGroups);
        }
    }
}
```

I will use a Devexpress GridControl to save and load user model. So I have a GridControl like this:

```
    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" >
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="FirstName"
                            Width="10"
                            FieldName="FirstName" />
            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="LastName"
                            Width="10"
                            FieldName="LastName" />
            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="UserName"
                            Width="10"
                            FieldName="UserName" />
            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="Password"
                            Width="10"
                            FieldName="Password">
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:PasswordBoxEditSettings />
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="UserGroups"
                            Width="15"
                            FieldName="UserGroups">
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding UserGroups}"
                                              DisplayMember="UserGroupName" >
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                            <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings />
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                    </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView x:Name="TableViewAllEmployees"
                           AutoWidth="True"
                           NewItemRowPosition="Top"
                           ShowGroupPanel="False" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Unfortunately in runtime combobox open in readonly mode and I cann't select any record form it.
Please tell me how to enable combobox.

In extra I use Devexpress, Caliburn in WPF project.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same effect when either the columns specified FieldName is invalid (and can't be bound) or the data type of the column's bound property (FieldName) is inconsistent with that of the items selected from the list.

You could also try setting the ComboBoxEditSettings ValueMember to "UserGroupId" (I've not tried binding a Column to a list of items before so I'm not sure about this).